# Finding Average String Length of Strings in Array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, average, string-length

I have an array of six quotes and I'm trying to find the average length of each quote. I'm thinking I need to create a new array of the string lengths, then average. But I can't figure out how to get the counts of the original array into the new array. How do I get the counts of the first array into the new array?

Comment: Could you include your array with quotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
arr = [1, 12, 123, 1234]                    // works with numbers too
avg = arr.join('').length / arr.length      // 10 / 4 = 2.5
console.log(avg)
```

Comment: strings are joined with `,` by default. you need to use `join('')`

Comment: That did it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your array of strings. For example:

```
['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd']
  .reduce((a, b, i, arr) => a + b.length / arr.length, 0)
```

Comment: @Slai it computes average partially, the result is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum up the total length of all quotes and them divide it by the length/size of the quotes array:

```
const quotes = [
    "Quote #1",
    "Longer quote",
    "Something...",
    ...
];

// Sum up all the quotes lengths
const totalQuotesLength = quotes.reduce(function (sum, quote) {
    return sum + quote.length;
}, 0);

// Calculate avg length of the quotes
const avgQuoteLength = (
    totalQuotesLength / quotes.length
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want to find the average length of strings in an array, you can do it like this:

```
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    total+=array[i].length;
}
var average = total/array.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use also `.reduce` with something like :

```
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const total = numbers.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
const average = total / numbers.length;
```

I hoe it will help !

Answer (score 0):

You could use forEach on each element without creating new arrays. May be long but readable:

https://jsfiddle.net/p19qbodw/ - run this in an opened console to see the result

```
var quotes = ["quotequote", "quote", "qu"]
charsSum = 0,
avarage;

quotes.forEach( (el) => {
charsSum += el.length;
});

 avarage = charsSum/quotes.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Join all array values to a single String and then you can calculate the  average length.

```
var yourArray = ["test", "tes", "test"],
    arrayLength = yourArray.length,
    joined = yourArray.join(''),
    result = joined.length / arrayLength;

console.log(result);
```